# Delete record from table if certain fields are empty upon closing a Form

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I am trying to get a button to close a Form and at the same time delete records on a table where certain fields are empty. I have this on the Form:

```
Private Sub cmdClose_Click()
Dim sql As String

sql = "DELETE *" _
     & " FROM [AlimentoporTanque]" _
     & " WHERE IsNull(Tanques) OR IsEmpty(Tanques) OR Tanques = "" OR Tanques = 0" _
     & " OR IsNull(Alimento) OR IsEmpty(Alimento) OR Alimento = "" OR Alimento = 0"
CurrentDb.Execute sql

DoCmd.Close , ""
End Sub
```

*AlimentoporTanque* is the Table's name and *Tanques* and *Alimento* the fields that should not be empty. When I click on the button I get following MsbBox popping up:

[image]

What am I doing wrong? How do I get this running? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working. This is the working code:

```
Private Sub cmdClose_Click()
Dim sql As String

sql = "DELETE *" _
     & " FROM [AlimentoporTanque]" _
     & " WHERE Tanques is Null" _
     & " OR Alimento is Null"

CurrentDb.Execute (sql)
DoCmd.Close , ""
End Sub
```

Comment: No need to build the sql every time. Change it to a static query and call it. If you decide to rename the columns later, the query will change automatically but VBA will give you trouble.

Comment: What is a static query and how do I call it?

Comment: A static query is a query you insert through access, Insert > New query.

Comment: To call it: `CurrentDb().QueryDefs("QueryName").Execute dbFailOnError`.